# Cast a Intersection type tp a single type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have intersection type that i'm trying to cast to a one of types in it but TypeScript won't let me do that (img beolow) idk why it won't let me do that any idea on how I can make it so I can cast to `Edge` type?

[image]

Comment: please provide reproducable example

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Include the code [formatted as code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918), not an image, so that others can reproduce the error themselves and investigate how to fix it. Have a look at the [tour] and [ask].